# EPPlus Conditional Format 'AddExpression' problem

Tags: epplus, conditional-formatting

I'm hoping someone who's got more experience than I have with EPPlus can point me in a better direction.

I have a table of values in one sheet (40 columns, roughly 600 rows), and a list of values in another sheet.  For each row, any value in the table that doesn't match the corresponding value in the list (same row) should be highlighted by setting the background to red.

I figured out a way to make this happen; but it is VERY slow. It is creating a conditional format rule for each of some 24000 cells, which would be a long time in any case, but the larger the list of rules gets, the longer each one takes to add; all in all, it takes a good half hour to run this loop:

```
    private static bool TryCreateConditionalFormatting(List<HVISettingSection> properties, int numberOfColumns, ExcelWorksheet ranges, ref ExcelWorksheet sxs)
    {
        bool success = true;


        int row = 4;
        foreach (HVISettingSection settings in properties)
        {
            row++; // to move beyond the section label
            foreach (var x in settings.SettingsList)
            {
                for (int col = 3; col < 3 + numberOfColumns; col++)
                {
                    var exacta = ranges.Cells[row, 3];
                    //ExcelFormulaAddress exactaAddr = new ExcelFormulaAddress(exacta.Address);
                    var neqRule = sxs.ConditionalFormatting.AddExpression(sxs.Cells[row, col]);
                    string _statement = string.Format(
                                         "AND(LEN(Ranges!{0})<>0, Ranges!{0}<>{1})",
                                         exacta.Address,
                                         new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelCellAddress(row, col).Address);

                    neqRule.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.Color = Color.Red;
                    neqRule.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    neqRule.Formula = _statement;
                }

            }
        }

        return success;
    }
```

I'm hoping there is some way to define a rule for an entire row, but to only change the format on individual cells; so instead of my formula being

```
string _statement = string.Format(
                                         "AND(LEN(Ranges!{0})<>0, Ranges!{0}<>{1})",
                                         exacta.Address,
                                         new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelCellAddress(row, col).Address);
```

I'd like something like this:

```
string _statement = string.Format(
                                         "AND(LEN(Ranges!{0})<>0, Ranges!{0}<>{1})",
                                         exacta.Address,
                                         <process each address in a range, separately>;
```

That last line is totally made up of course, pseudocode if you like.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks to all

Comment: I already tried.  After knocking my head on the wall, I gave up and I create conditionnal formatting for each cell.

Comment: Between the two of us, a new wall will soon be needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the answer I was hoping to find, but it may be the best I can do.

I've found no way to actually do what I wanted, but I did find another way to solve MY problem.  I've just created a template spreadsheet, with all of the conditional formatting on the page (I'm fortunate that the details aren't content-dependent other than the number of rows; so I just created a BUNCH of rows, arbitrarily more than I need)

I saved that XSLX file as a .Net file resource.  Then, when I start up, I do this:

```
using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create)))
{
    // this is the xslx file resource; just write it to the file
    bw.Write(Properties.Resources.SampleStatus);  
}

//  Now, turn around and read that file into EPP ExcelPackage
FileInfo myFile = new FileInfo(filename);
using (ExcelPackage ExcelFile = new ExcelPackage(myFile))
{
    // Access the worksheets in the excel file
    ExcelWorksheet sxsWorksheet = ExcelFile.Workbook.Worksheets["Side-By-Side"];
    ExcelWorksheet rangesWorksheet = ExcelFile.Workbook.Worksheets["Ranges"];

    // add all of the data content here

    // add any additional worksheets you want

    // ... and save it!
    ExcelFile.Save();
}
```

It's fast -- maybe 5 seconds, rather than 20-30 minutes.  I hope it helps someone else.